# have on someone or something - is this an expression?

Tags: meaning

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/latvia-coalition-holds-power-pro-putin-force-tops-073931046.html

> Concern is also running high over the impact that tit-for-tat sanctions between Moscow and Brussels over the Ukraine crisis could **have on** this tiny Baltic state, which is heavily reliant on trade with Russia.

Is that an expression? I tried to find the meaning of that phrase by doing a Google search but I really came up with nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression used here is

> to have (an) impact on someone/something

but it has been split up in your example. See also http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impact?show=0&t=1412527328, under "intransitive verb".